# fopen make a 0 named directory instead of file

Tags: php, html, fopen

I'm new to PHP, want to make a user defined HTML page (or even text file), but when i use fopen, a folder named 0 is created in local folder, Here is my code

```
<?php

$ifilename = "A195-2256";

$filename = $ifilename + ".html";

$myfile = fopen($filename, "w+") or die("Unable to open file!");

$txt = "Some text here";

fwrite($myfile, $txt);

fclose($myfile);

?>
```

Anybody who can help me?

Comment: The `.` notation is actually the concatenator in php, what you've done is attempted to add two strings, the result being false, with a numerical representation of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concatenation operator you are using is wrong. For php you need to use the `.` instead of the `+` operator.  That's why php is creating a folder named 0 for you. File with out extension is considered as a folder in file I/O functions in php.

Your code

```
$filename = $ifilename + ".html";
```

Updated snippet .

```
$filename = $ifilename . ".html";
```

See the fixed full version of your code below

```
<?php

$ifilename = "A195-2256";

$filename = $ifilename .".html";

$myfile = fopen($filename, "w+") or die("Unable to open file!");

$txt = "Some text here";

fwrite($myfile, $txt);

fclose($myfile);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP use '.' for joining strings, not '+'.

```
$ifilename = "A195-2256";
$filename = $ifilename . ".html";
```

In your expression, you are creating a value 0.